# I am unable to run nc -lk <port number> on my Mac. What is the replacement? Tying to run a word count program, a simple pyspark streaming application

Tags: python, sockets, pyspark, tcp, streaming

So I have taken this code off the internet from a GitHub source
https://github.com/tirthajyoti/Spark-with-Python/blob/master/Python-and-Spark-for-Big-Data-master/Spark%20Streaming/Introduction%20to%20Spark%20Streaming.ipynb

I have run the code and it is working, it is listening on port 9999. I can see each second go by that it is writing the timestamp.

I have typed the command below, on my Mac terminal after running the python program

```
nc -lk 9999
```

Now, supposedly after I type this command in. I can type the words on the terminal and the pyspark streaming application would record the count of each word.

Unfortunately this command doesn't work on mac/unix. Is there a way around this.
I don't have VMware running so I am running this program running on my single Mac.

It is coming back with **nc: invalid option -- k**

I believe the **nc -lk 9999** command works on linux but it doesn't work on my Mac which is the problem and I have searched around for a solution.

Below is the python code I pulled from the link to run...

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

# Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "NetworkWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

# Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
# Firewalls might block this!
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

# Split each line into words
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))

# Count each word in each batch
pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

# Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
wordCounts.print()


ssc.start()             # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

If there is solution that could help, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

As `netcat -lk 9999` wasn't working. There was an option of installing a similar version inform of 'ncat' after searching the web. Nmap needed to be installed to use ncat. Use ... `brew install nmap`. As mentioned the package comes with ncat.

Check out https://nmap.org/ncat/ for more info.

Using...

```
ncat -l -k 9999
```

worked and typing in words after the command was counted in the pyspark program now.